# Accessing a column by it's name in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I have the following table:

```
column_name | a | b
--------------------
     a      | 0 | 1 
--------------------
     b      | 2 | 3
```

Is it possible to write a select statement that will return:

```
result
------
   0
   3
```

(I want to pick a column depending on the name specified in column_name)

The trick is that I do not know how many columns will I have and what will be their names (except for the column_name column)

I can't create temporary tables, functions and so on. Yes, it's a part of a task on a SQL course on my university, still not the task itself, so I believe I can ask for help here.

Comment: I am sure, the SQL course provides the question more clearly ...

Comment: You'd need dynamic SQL. Read up on PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` command. Or maybe you are looking for crosstabulation / pivot, in which case you want the `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when column_name='b' then b else a end
from ...
```

basically? it'd get incredibly ugly tedious for more than just a couple columns

Comment: I forgot to specify that this was just an example and that I do not know the number of columns nor their names in that task. I updated the question so it says it now.

Comment: then you'll have to use dynamic sql. e.g. `select column_name`, then build a new sql string to `select value_retrieved_from_other_query` and execute that statement. you cannot use "values" from one part of a query as sql keywords or field/table names elsewhere in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postgresql json data type (and its related features):

```
select row_to_json(table_name)->>(row_to_json(table_name)->>'column_name') from table_name;
```